# Flex equal for .Net ListItem

Tags: .net, apache-flex

I am trying to do something similar to the code below but in Flex. Code below is .Net. Any ideas?`

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="lstBufferDistance" style="Z-INDEX: 125; LEFT: 488px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 112px"
        tabIndex="4" runat="server" Width="72px" Height="16px">
        <asp:ListItem Value="200">200 ft</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="500" Selected="True">500 ft</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1000">1000 ft</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1500">1500 ft</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="5280">1 Mile</asp:ListItem>
      </asp:dropdownlist>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know .NET, but it looks like that code is a drop down list with a dataProvider.  Something like this should work:

```
<s:DropDownList id="lstBufferDistance" selectedIndex="1">
 <s:dataProvider>
  <s:ArrayCollection>
   <fx:Object label="200 ft" value="200"/>
   <fx:Object label="500 ft" value="500"/>
   <fx:Object label="1000 ft" value="1000"/>
   <fx:Object label="1500 ft" value="1500"/>
   <fx:Object label="1 Mile" value="5200"/>
  </s:ArrayCollection>
 </s:dataProvider>
</s:DropdownList>
```

So, this uses the Spark DropDownList.  It creates a dataProvider in MXML which is made up of generic objects.  The generic objects have a property named label; which is used by the DropDownList as the display field for each item.  The generic objects can also have other properties--in this case value--which can represent some other data about the item.

Normally in "real world" apps you wouldn't use a generic object for a dataProvider, but instead you'd create a custom class.

I used the selectedIndex property to set a default value to the 2nd item in the list.

Comment: Tweaked it a tiny bit because I could not get dataProvider or fx to work. So instead I used a mx:ComboBox, mx:ArrayCollection, and mx:Object

Comment: FX and the Spark ComboBox will only work in Flex 4 or later; if you are using a lower version; then the code I provided will cause errors.  It also looks like I forgot to close the dataProvider.  I'll fix that.

Comment: That would be why I'm using 3.5.